# Allow "title" attribute in allowed HTML <tags>

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor

`title` is a global HTML attribute applicable to any HTML `<tag>` with the purpose of adding some 'extra information' to the contents of that tag. When used, it's rendered as a `tooltip` with the contents provided for its value.

As per [the answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) the `title` attribute is allowed only for `<a>` and `<img>` tags, and leaving out the importance of describing an image, we're left with only using links either as tags or via Markdown, but there are cases when you would want to convey some extra details in your post that's not suitable for a link, but rather reinforce a statement or describe implied extra details, for example:

<strike>[some statement](http://null.null)</strike> or 
**[true](http://false.false/)**

I should also note the option of using Markdown tags, for example [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), with its predefined behavior.

Aside the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is there a way one could use the ability to tooltip that I've missed?

Comment: What is wrong with using parentheses for these asides? It's grammatically correct.

Comment: +1 simply because you thought your argument through.

Comment: @random sometimes using parentheses or too many parenthesis bloats the text. And there are *some* cases of using { parens [inside (parens inside -parens-)]}. And there are the cases when the information is optional and would make the text redundant if used in parenthesis.

Comment: @ProfPickle here on Meta voting feature requests should be based on your personal opinion about the request: +1 if you agree and want to see it come to life, or -1 if you don't want it getting implemented.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I guess the dev-team implements new-features by popular demand, so you should -1 only of it's a bad idea or you don't want it by some reason and don't vote if it's the same for you, because otherwise if only a few +1 it it would sit in the back of the queue anyway.

Comment: @kaᵠ not always. There are requests with +500 that get declined or no dev attention whatsoever and there are requests with negative score getting implemented. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-completed?page=38&sort=votes&pagesize=50) for list of downvoted requests which got implemented.

Comment: I agree with random here. Use parentheses where necessary, or just formulate your sentences in a way where you get the information across without having to use them. Hiding text in a tooltip where it's unexpected doesn't help anyone in the end. I can't imagine any scenario where this would be a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

I worry that this wouldn't actually ever convey any information unless every use of it was followed by "‍(hover for more information)"<sup><strike>1</strike></sup> which would defeat the purpose.

I have no objection to more fully supporting innocuous corners of the HTML spec, but this seems so esoteric as to not warrant expending any development effort.

<sup>1. <strike>Is the earlier quote character left obnoxiously stranded on the previous line for you?  Does it make you twitch?  [Me too.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175417/137004)</strike> [Fixed!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175639/137004)</sup>