# Quotes not properly attached to parentheses in Markdown layout?

Tags: support

I just posted [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175415/137004) that happened to have a quoted parenthesized statement that fell on the line-wrap boundary and was surprised to see the quote character left stranded while the parenthesized statement was wrapped to the next line:
[image: orphaned quote]

With a bit of extraneous verbiage I pretty confidently suspect that I can also recreate the problem here "(like so)" (at least on my computer).

Is this intended behavior?  A bug in SO's Markdown layout engine or its parent?  Some oddity of my browser or HTML-layout more broadly?

Comment: The weird thing is that escaping the parenthesis doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: doesn't seem to happen for `{[(` and not for single quote `'` also. looks like an exception

Comment: It happens to me in Chrome26/Win7 as well "(current version)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Markdown or us. If the browser decides it wants to break the line at that point, that's the browser's decision. If it bothers you very much, you can insert a `&zwj;` between the quotes and the parens.